# What is optimal way to use branches with GIT in this scenario

Tags: git

I am developing CMS for internal company purpose but we have many installations of it on different sites which differs mainly in templates, html etc.

So I have one master branch which contains pure installation of CMS, then multiple installations forked from master.

So when I find for example bug working in one of branches, what should I do now? In the end I want to have bug fixed on all installations and master also. My suggestion:

Switch back to master and do changes, then merge back to branches
Problems:
1) I do not have necessary situation on master, co I can't test it on master, so I would need repetitively switch branches and merge
2) Maybe I will merge also changes that I don't want to.

What I would like to do is following:
I found a bug, so I would like to say: now I am working on bug and every change I want to record and reapply everywhere (but without changes I made before this statement)

Is it possible?

EDIT: Maybe it is not totally obvious but CMS has it's core and parts that you need to change for every website (templates etc.) and core is part that nearly doesn't change between particular installations and it is where I need to do bug fixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm not mistaken you are looking for git cherry-pick

From the help:

```
git-cherry-pick - Apply the changes introduced by some existing commits
```

This is used to grab fixes from a different branch into the branch you are working on. The fix needs to be isolated in a separate commit though for this to work smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

What you are actually planning will lead to a disaster. You will have to merge every new feature or bugfix into every branch. Versioning will get a hell. After a short time you'll get lost in branches. Lost ...  lost  ..... l......

You are still there? :) Code your application in a flexible way so that it can be configured for working in multiple scenarios using the application configuration, not different branches. [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) is something you should read about.

Comment: You know, the CMS is mostly modular but you have rare situations when you *have to* hack core and I really thought this out. But anyway, I need to use bug fixes for all my installations.